# PIVOT from JOIN tables

Tags: sql, join, pivot, case

I have a large database and in this database, there are two tables I need to pull information from.  I have pulled all the data I need out of the two tables by using both a JOIN and a CASE WHEN. Here is a screen shot from the output

[SQL Server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5IYx.png)

This is the code that I used to pull the data:

```
SELECT [PORTMultiMax].[dbo].cardholdertable.cardid as CardID,CardHolderTable.FirstName as FirstName,CardHolderTable.LastName as LastName, CardHolderTable.InitLet as MI, CardHolderPersonalDataXrTable.PersonalDataItem as Data,
  CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '4' THEN 'SSN'
         WHEN PersonalDataID = '22' THEN 'Employer'
         WHEN PersonalDataID = '30' THEN 'Training Type'
         WHEN PersonalDataID = '32' THEN 'Primary Sponsor'
         WHEN PersonalDataID = '37' THEN 'Training Date'
         ELSE NULL END AS Description
  FROM [PORTMultiMax].[dbo].[CardHolderTable]
  join [PORTMultiMax].[dbo].[CardHolderPersonalDataXrTable]
  on cardholdertable.CardID=CardHolderPersonalDataXrTable.CardID
    where PersonalDataID IN (4,22,30,32,33,37)
    order by LastName
```

The tables involved are named: CardHolderTable and CardHolderPersonalDataXrTable 
What I need to do next is get rid of the duplicate name entries in the data. So for example, "JAMES AARON" has multiple rows due to him having multiple descriptors ("Training Date, TrainingType, Employer, and SSN").

I wanted to try and use a PIVOT to pull the row data out and put them in columns named "SSN, Employer, etc...". My problem is I have never used PIVOT before and I am confused on how to apply a PIVOT code to my current SQL query.

PLEASE HELP. Thank you so much

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Or ask another question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Given your query, I think conditional aggregation is simpler:

```
SELECT ch.FirstName, ch.LastName
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as is_SSN
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '22' THEN ELSE 0 END) as is_Employer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '30' THEN ELSE 0 END) as is_TrainingType,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '32' THEN ELSE 0 END) as is_PrimarySponsor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonalDataID = '37' THEN ELSE 0 END) as is_TrainingDate
from [PORTMultiMax].[dbo].[CardHolderTable] ch join
     [PORTMultiMax].[dbo].[CardHolderPersonalDataXrTable] cp
     on ch.CardID = cp.CardID
where PersonalDataID IN (4, 22, 30, 32, 33, 37)
group by ch.FirstName, ch.LastName;
```

Comment: That definately gets me closer but I need the data from the personaldataItem column to be placed under the newly created columns. The idea being that if the person's name is John Smith and he has an SSN, employer and trainingtype, then the result would be:                                                      John Smith 123-45-6789 Disney World Badge Disney World 01/01/2015